# QGIS Time manager

Tags: qgis, raster, timemanager

I am trying to use the Time Manager plugin in QGIS to create a time series of some raster data. I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'featureCount'
```

Can anyone explain to me what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report.